# LibGDX sound playing problem

Tags: libgdx, sound, asset-management, waves

I'm making a game and I want to play sounds in it.
I have AssetManager which loads the sounds and I made a class which has playSound(String sound) method. This method calls the get() method of the assets manager with the string, creates Sound type file and calls it's play() method.
The code:

```
public void playSound(String sound) {
    Sound file = gameRenderer.assetsManager.get("sfx/sounds/" + sound + ".wav");
    file.play();
}
```

It works fine.
But then I noticed there is a log that occurs every time the sound is played:

```
AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
```

I also noticed a small "tick" sound in the end of the sound every time it's played in the game.
I read about it and from what I've learned it has something to so with sample rate. I tried many types of sounds (44KHz, 48KHz, and lower values too) but it doesn't stop printing that log.
I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

If it really has something to do with sample rate, does it mean I need to have different types of file of the same sound (With every sample rate)?
If it does, my game would be heavy...
I'm using Nexus 5.
Thanks!